# Win 8 apps fire an event on finger swipe

Tags: javascript, touch, windows-runtime, winjs

I want to fire an event, when user swipes his finger on a specified div.
for example : when a user swipes a finger on a div a particular function should be called.

Answer (score 1):

This will add the event handler:

```
document.getElementById('divId').addEventListener('mspointermove', handler, false);
```

Then you would have to recognize if it's a touch event or an event with the mouse.

```
function handler(event) {
    if (eventObject.pointerType === 2) {
        // touch event
    }
}
```

Here is a [complete guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968035.aspx) for the touch events. msgesturestart/change/end is probably what you want to utilize.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already, what exactly I want is that I have a calendar, on that I have a left bar which displays months and have two buttons. right now next month is displayed by clicking the buttons and calling the nextmonth() function, the same I want to do with a touch gesture, like when u swipe the month should change that is the nextmonth() should be called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full Gesture Recognizer functionality from WinRT for the best experience. MSDN has a fully worked through sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-26918bb3). This will then allow you to grab the manipulation for a DIV and work with it as appropriate. A simple walk through is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465869.aspx). Note the need to:

1. Create a MSGesture object
2. Capture MSPointerDown, and add the pointer ID to the gesture instance created in 1.

An additional consideration is to look at your experience and consider if using [mandatory snap points](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scrolling-panning-and-47d70d4c), and multiple items in a scroller may work for your experience.

Some sample code:

```
<div id="touchMe" style="width:500px; height: 500px; background-color: yellow; "></div>
```

JavaScript, run when touchMe is available:

```
var v = document.getElementById("touchMe");
v.addEventListener("MSGestureStart", function () {
    console.log("foo");
});

var gestureThing = new MSGesture();
gestureThing.target = v;
v.dooHicker = gestureThing;

v.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", function (e) {
    gestureThing.addPointer(e.pointerId);
    console.log("down");
});

v.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("click");
});
```

Comment: I tried the following code :     
this.element.querySelector(".bartouch").addEventListener("MSGestureStart", function () {
                 that.nextMonth();

               }); and have tried MSPointerUp and MSPointerDown also but of no help..

Comment: What you asked it to do. It will notify you when the gesture starts. You need to define exactly what your gesture is -- thats why I linked the sample. A Gesture involves many different parts. There are some built in gesture recognizers, which are also linked from the sample.

Comment: My requirement is when the gesture ends it should call my function, its like when I swipe my finger a next page comes.

Comment: How far? How much variance from a straight line will you accept? There is not a "simple" answer. You need to look closely at the sample I linked to. Your need to likely look at the manipulationTranslateXRails type of gesture and work with that.